# Redirect to previous page when page is not found

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Hi I want to redirect to previous page and to not show a not found page.
I tried this, but it doesnt work (nextJS 13+)

in a file called not-found.tsx:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function NotFoundPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  return router.back();
}
```

Comment: What if the person copies past the not found generating URL directly in the browser ? There will no previous page. Is'it an option to redirect to a fixed url, like "/"?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. And even though `document.referrer` doesn't work in the NextJS app itself. It does work in the not-found.js file.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function NotFoundPage() {
  const router = useRouter();

  const referrerUrl = document.referrer ? new URL(document.referrer) : null;
  const previousPath = referrerUrl && (referrerUrl.pathname + referrerUrl.search + referrerUrl.hash);

  return previousPath ? router.push(previousPath) : router.back();
}
```

Comment: This way user will still be redirected to the Not Found page before going back to the previous page. The ideal solution should prevent users from redirecting to the Not Found page and directly going back to the previous page.

Comment: @AlishSatani - From a user's perspective. If they visit a page that does not exist, and you just redirect them to the previous page without telling them what is happening, it might be a little confusing. So, showing them "Sorry, the page does not exist" and giving them a way forward, either by going back to the previous page or going to the home page is a better experience.

But I do realize that this is not what the initial question was asking. I think I missed that part of the statement. So you are correct. This will take the user to the Not found page first.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const NotFoundPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Redirect to the previous page after a delay (if needed)
    setTimeout(() => {
      router.back();
    }, 3000); // Redirect after 3 seconds (adjust as needed)
  }, [router]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Redirecting to the previous page...</p>
      {/* You can show a message or spinner while redirecting */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotFoundPage;
```

In your _app.tsx or _app.js file, include a custom 404 handler using getServerSideProps:

```
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ res, err }) {
  // Redirect to the previous page if it's a 404 error
  if (err && err.code === 'ENOENT') {
    res.writeHead(307, { Location: '/' }); // Redirect status code
    res.end(); // End the response
  }

  return {
    props: {},
  };
}

export default MyApp;
```